# making an eloquent relation for users that follow each other

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an app like Instagram in which users can follow each other, so I put this in my User model:

```
    public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follow_rel', 'follower_id', 'followed_id');
}

public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follow_rel', 'followed_id', 'follower_id');
}

public function follow(User $user)
{
    $this->following()->syncWithoutDetaching($user);
}

public function unfollow(User $user)
{
    $this->following()->detach($user);
}
```

and this is my migration:

```
        Schema::create('follow_rel', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->boolean('accepted')->default(false);
        $table->unsignedInteger('follower_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('followed_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

It works fine but I don't know how to deal with 'accepted' column.
Just like Instagram, I want the first user to send a request and if the second user's account is private, set the accepted column to false, so when I write a query to get follow_relations, skip those that are not accepted(just like soft delete).
how should I modify my relation to achieve this?
or should I make another table named 'requst_rel' and after accepting, move it to the 'follow_rel' table?
any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return a relation with ->wherePivot()

```
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follow_rel', 'follower_id', 'followed_id')->wherePivot(accepted, 1);
```

Unfortunately ->syncWithoutDetaching() doesn't work with pivot tables. You'll have to figure out the process manually:

```
public function follow(User $user)
{
    if (! $this->following->contains($user)) {
        $this->following()->attach($user, ['accepted' => 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, and how can I access this column while setting a new relation? e.g. in Auth::user()->follow($user); how can I set the accepted column to true or false?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand, but it sounds like you want to query relationships that have only been accepted? If so, you want to use the `wherePivot` method:

```
$followers = $user->followers()-> wherePivot('accepted', true)->get();
```

Or you could make a method on the model:

```
public function accepted_followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follow_rel', 'followed_id', 'follower_id')->wherePivot('accepted', true);
}

$followers = $user->accepted_followers;
```

Comment: thanks, and how can I access this column while setting a new relation? e.g. in Auth::user()->follow($user); how can I set the accepted column to true or false?